# Automated distribution for Java project

Tags: java, distribution

I have to make a tool for automated distribution of the Java code. Basically, I have a repository with compiled files, and about 50 locations to distribute the same code.

Does anyone know some opensource tool which can help me in this process?

Comment: @komunca.. U r asking for opensource development tools..?

Comment: You could try if rsync fits your needs

Comment: Do you essentially want to deploy an application update by pushing it? Which environment are you targeting, do you have full access to the machines?

Comment: I want a opensource tool to help me distribute code.

I'm sorry, I didn't explain everything. I have a tomcat based aplication in my svn repository. Also I have more than 50 independent distributions of that code. Each of them has their tomcat, db, etc.
And I wont to find some tool which I can use to move new/changed files, ... to all of my remote installations. 

I have full access to remote machines.

Comment: @komunca, is there any reason you can't use svn?

Comment: I think I cant use svn to install application remotely. I can use some tool which can deply svn revision over ftp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are speaking about easy deployment of java applications, use JNLP. The only thing user has to do in this case is to surf to URL.

If you wish to do it without any user participation I believe the solution depends on target platform:

- Use SSH for Unix platforms
- WNI or telnet for windows platforms.

To make the solution more portable you can run

wget THE-JNLP-URL

on target machine using SSH for unix like platforms.

I do not know built-in command like wget for windows. But you can implement this in VBS or JS and then invoke the script using `cscript` over WMI or telnet.

Good luck.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't explain everything. I have a tomcat based aplication in my svn repository. Also I have more than 50 independent distributions of that code. Each of them has their tomcat, db, etc.
And I wont to find some tool which I can use to move new/changed files, ... to all of my remote installations.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can distribute it out with rsync, or you can use Java WebStart to let the user JVM download and invoke the software as needed.   For Windows based clients this is usually the easiest, especially when you want people to update to a newer version.